# Browser support for specific jQuery version

Tags: jquery, browser, version

jQuery [states](https://jquery.com/browser-support/) that supported browser are

> Chrome: (Current - 1) and Current
>   Edge: (Current - 1) and Current
>   Firefox: (Current - 1) and Current
>   Internet Explorer: 9+

v2 dropped support for IE 6-8.

The problem: what exact Chrome versions are supported by ,say, jQuery 2.1 (and jQuery 1.11)?
  They are released on the same day in Jan 2014 http://blog.jquery.com/2014/01/24/jquery-1-11-and-2-1-released/

Comment: "(Current - 1) and Current" browser for only current version of jQuery?

Comment: That's how I read it. In determining support for older versions, it looks like you're left to fend for yourself with release notes and whatever else you can scrounge up.

Answer (score 4):

the JQuery site does indicate the following

> Chrome: (Current and Current - 1)
>  Edge: (Current and Current -
>   1)
>  Firefox: (Current and Current - 1)
>  Explorer: 9+

Which means that the official release of JQuery is supported by the current browser version + plus its predecessor.

What I have found is that Chrom(e|ium) version 45.0.2454.0 supports all the way up to JQuery 3.2.1

I've been trying to test various browser versions to see what version of JQuery is supported. I can only go back to 45.0.2454.0 as I cannot find installs for anything older.

For future reference I have found the following to be true:

> FireFox version 6 and greater supports JQuery 3.2.1
> FireFox >= to
>   3.5.1 and < 6 supports up to version 1.11.3
> FireFox < 3.5.1 supports up to 1.6.4
>
> Opera 12.02 and greater supports JQuery 3.2.1
> Opera < 12.02 supports
>   up to version 1.11.3

Answer (score 2):

Here trying to figure it out as for a same version of jQuery, some versions of browsers are deployed and they (jquery ppl) did'n update it so...

Version 0.3 Browser A released.
version x.x.x jQuery released.

release notes -> browser support Browser A (current and -1)
(which would mean that jQuery latest version supports Browser A on versions 0.2 and 0.3).
then version 0.0.4 Browser A released.
jQuery version are the same. 
It can't mean that same jQuery version that supported 0.2 and 0.3 now supports 0.3 and 0.4 by logic.

Moreover, you try it with Browser A 0.1 and it work fine too so... Is there any version history with compatibility that i couldn't find yet?

Well, i found this that is telling me nothing new: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery

i found a snippet from 12 years ago (gosh damn) that told me this:
Internet Explorer 5.5+, Firefox 1.0+, Safari 1.3+, and Opera 8.5+
i guess this was 1.x.x of jQuery (or older).

But only we can take for sure is that:
For Internet Explorer 6-8, Opera 12.1x or Safari 5.1+, use jQuery 1.12.

If you don't need this shitty old versions... Newer versions of jQuery 2.x.x

i don't know the difference on support between 2.x.x and 3.x.x

Hope we can make a little wiki here. I suppose to dig more we'll need to ask for the compatibility of specific properties/methods/whatever listed on changelogs.

```
Version 1.0: First stable release.
Version 2.0: Dropped IE 6–8 support for performance improvements and reduction in filesize
Version 3.0: Promises/A+ support for Deferreds, $.ajax and $.when, .data() HTML5-compatible
```

Taking this as start point, if i need promises i need to check for its compatibility:

https://caniuse.com/#feat=promises

Hope it helps

Cheers